# compile multiple C codes to one single assembly file

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compilation

I want to compile multiple C files to a single assembly file (they are interconnected and when you compile it you will have a binary file). Is it possible in GCC?

For example take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/onpu-lvt/algo-test). The make file will generate a single file (a binary one).

However I want to compile them to assembly, instrument the code and then compile them to binary. Obviously it will be easier for me if I have all the assembly files in a single *.s file.

Any idea?

Comment: `#include` all those files into a single `.c` file and compile it

Comment: Smell like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @mvidelgauz It won't work without modifications in most cases.

Comment: So... What do you *really* need to do?

Comment: @EugeneSh. You are right. That's why I wrote comment and not an answer. I just hope OP will manage further...

Comment: guys guys guys be gentle to my question :-) . What is vague in the question? I already gave a example link!. I need to generate a single assembly file for that repo. Which I searched but could not find any source which explain that.

Comment: @SamaAzari We are as gentle as possible. But it is likely that you ask from us to help you solve a problem you don't really have.

Comment: What do you mean I do not really have a problem? Can you elaborate that? I was looking around for ways to generate a single .asm file from multiple C codes. I could not. I could find it for binary (which is obvious) but not something similar for assembly code. Which I think can be useful for others in future. Specially those who have to instrument the assembly code and then compile it to binary.

Comment: @SamaAzari Usually you instrument every assembly file individually. Note that even if you have a C program comprising only a single source file, not all code that ends up in the binary is contained in the assembly file as the linker is going to add startup and runtime code.

Comment: @SamaAzari Read the link in the second comment.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know what is XY problem. But as I said clearly I want to instrument assembly codes. and I need a single .s file (preferably since it is easier as mentioned above). Maybe I am wrong. But I think I explained what I want to do and just what I think is an answer.

Comment: @FUZxxl I think your comment can be right. I actually can individually compile the codes and then maybe compile them to one single code.

Comment: @SamaAzari What kind of instrumentation do you want to do anyway?

Comment: @FUZxxl pushing some registers value to the memory in every function prolog and epilog.

Comment: Can't you do that with asm macro into c code directly?

Comment: I can but it impose additional overhead. Also the gcc will never let me add extra codes before function prolog.

Comment: @LPs Additionally If I do it, the instrumentation needs the source code rather than assembly code. Which is a "selling point" of my idea. meaning that my instrumentation will be less intrusive than others.

Comment: @SamaAzari And why do you need to have all functions in one file for that? Can't you instrument every file individually?

Comment: @SamaAzari Note that such tools already exist. `gcc` supports the `-pg` option to generate instrumentation suitable for `gprof`.

Comment: @FUZxxl it is not customize-able instrumentation.

Comment: @SamaAzari What do you want to customize?

Comment: @FUZxxl The instrumentation code.

Comment: @SamaAzari Yes, but for what reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see three approaches:

- Use `cat` to concatenate the assembly files. This should work unless two or more translation units use a static variable with the same name. This might be problematic if labels are used twice. You can preprocess the individal files with a sed-script like this to make the labels unique:

  ```
  s/\.L\([[:alnum:]]*\)/.L$ident\1/
  ```

  where `$ident` is a unique string for each assembly file. This turns `.Lfoo` into `.Lidentfoo`.
- Make a C source file that looks like this and compile it, same caveat as before:

  ```
  #include "module1.c"
  #include "module2.c"
  ...
  #include "modulen.c"
  ```
- Use `ld -r` to perform a partial link on a set of object files. This gives you one large object file containing the content of the other files. You can then use a tool like `objconv` to disassemble the object file, instrument it and reassemble. Note that this might not what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to glue all sources together with [Amalgamate](https://github.com/vinniefalco/Amalgamate) and then generate assembly output.